# A NSOperationQueue error I'm trying to figure out from Crashlytics

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, ios10

I got this error on Crashlytics this morning and I can't firgure out what the problem is. It would be awesome to get your opinions about it. I thInk it's most likely a multi threading issue. But I'm not able to pin point exactly what it is.

[image]

EDIT: I dug a little deeper and here's the code that's failing:

Also, I've figured out that the error is:

Could not cast value of type '__NSSingleObjectArrayI' (0x1aa60bca0) to 'NSMutableArray' (0x1aa60bd90).
2016-09-22 08:29:34.136764 GrabbnGo[4204:822290] Could not cast value of type '__NSSingleObjectArrayI' (0x1aa60bca0) to 'NSMutableArray' (0x1aa60bd90).

This was working perfectly all this while and it's suddenly causing problems and the app is already on the store :/

```
json = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options: NSJSONReadingOptions()) as? [String: AnyObject]
            let str = NSString(data: data!, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
            print(str)
            let OrderDictionary = json as NSDictionary
            let result = OrderDictionary.objectForKey("result") as! NSMutableArray
```

Comment: Any reason you're not showing the source? Some context around line 521?

Comment: I've add the source and the actual error message. The last line is the one that's failing.

Comment: There is lots of material based around crashing on '!'. '!' is a source of crashes in Swift programs, period. This question should be closed and you should look for keywords like: "force unwrapping causing crash / how to avoid / safe unwrapping / error handling of Optionals"

Comment: Alright. Thanks. I'll do that. Any idea as to why it could have started crashing suddenly but has been working okay for a month?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, this sort of has a unique answer. Basically, you're misusing `NSJSONSerialization`, and it's a time-bomb bug that eventually bit you.

According to the documentation:

https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/jsonserialization

> All objects are instances of NSString, NSNumber, NSArray, NSDictionary, or NSNull.

This is a very simple and clear sentence. You should respect it. It says nothing about `NSMutableArray`, only `NSArray`. The JSON parser is using whatever compatible (subclass) object for the `NSArray` that it so chooses. If there's only one item in the array, it appears that the internal type `__NSSingleObjectArray` is a lot more efficient, probably both in speed and memory.

There is almost certainly a change on the server (or customer behavior) such that `result` now (often? sometimes? always?) has only 1 item in it, so the JSON parser made a different choice that you're not supposed to care about.

All you need to do is change it to `NSArray` and construct an `NSMutableArray` from it if you really need:

```
let myJSONParsedArray: NSArray = ...
let myMutableArray = NSMutableArray(myJSONParsedArray)
```

But first learn about why force unwrapping is so dangerous, especially in a network code environment, when you can't trust any data at all, regarding type and value and maliciousness, ever!!

Comment: Thanks a lot. This really helped. An update is on the way to the store to get this fixed. :)